# PDfkit wkhtmltopdf footer not coming on ubuntu working on windows

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

Footer not coming in ubuntu when generating PDF using pdfkit Wkhtmltopdf using these options

```
options={
            'page-size': 'A4',
            'margin-top': '0.2in',
            'margin-bottom': '0.89in',
            'margin-right': '0.1in',
            'margin-left': '0.1in',
            'encoding': "UTF-8",
            'footer-right': "Page [page] of [topage]",
            'footer-center':"""MadOverBuilding AI Private Limited I (mob)""",
            'footer-font-size': "8",
            'footer-spacing':5,
            'header-spacing':10,
            'header-font-size':"8",
            'custom-header': [
                ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
            ],
            'no-outline': None
        }
```